# How accurate is distanceFromLocation on Iphone vs calculating it yourself in cartesian cordinates?

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

In the Iphone SDK the `distanceFromLocation:` says it doesn't use altitude at all.  If I'm writing an app to track how far I walk/cycle/ect (yes I know there are a number that do this already), I'm curious how much that matters.  Does anyone have experience with this?

When I say cartesian cords I mean something like this (in C#, not objective C):

```
        double lattitude, longitude, altitude, x, y, z, x1, y1, z1, S;
        double a = 6378137, C, f = 1 / 298.257224;

        lattitude = <insert degrees> * Math.PI / 180.0;
        longitude = <insert degrees> * Math.PI / 180.0;
        altitiude = <insert altitude>

        C= 1 / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Cos(lattitude),2.0) + Math.Pow((1 - f),2.0) *Math.Pow(Math.Sin(lattitude),2.0)));
        S = Math.Pow(1 - f, 2.0) * C;
        x = (a*C+altitude) * Math.Cos(lattitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
        y = (a*C+altitude) *Math.Cos(lattitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
        z = (a*S+altitude) * Math.Sin(lattitude);

        lattitude = <insert degrees new> * Math.PI / 180.0;
        longitude = <insert degrees new> * Math.PI / 180.0;
        altitiude = <insert altitude new>;


        x1 = (a * C + altitude) * Math.Cos(lattitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
        y1 = (a * C + altitude) * Math.Cos(lattitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
        z1 = (a * S + altitude) * Math.Sin(lattitude);

        double distance;
        distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1 - x, 2.0) + Math.Pow(y1 - y, 2.0) + Math.Pow(z1 - z, 2.0));
```

Does anyone know how much of a difference it actually makes? Essentially how it is calculated precisely on iphone?  Great circle distance?  I can't seem to find the answer anywhere

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) say:

> "This method measures the distance
>   between the two locations by tracing a
>   line between them that follows the
>   curvature of the Earth. The resulting
>   arc is a smooth curve and does not
>   take into account specific altitude
>   changes between the two locations."

To me, that implies Great Circle distance (in fact, it's nearly the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) of it).

My understanding (though I'm certainly no expert) is that great circle calculations (such as [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)) are very typical, and generally considered "good enough" for most applications.

There's probably way more information than you want on the topic [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108965/taking-altitude-into-account-when-calculating-geodesic-distance) is semi-related as well.

If you're really concerned about it, I'd try a few different algorithms, and see if you can determine which best suits your needs.