# How can I find 3d distance between lat/lon/alt points?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gis

There is plenty of information on finding the distances between two WGS 84 lat/lon points but not much on the distance between two WGS 84 /lat/lon/alt points, are there any libraries that can do this? can anyone point me to information about this? I am using it for a UAV collision avoidance system so it needs to be accurate for distances 0-20m away further than that I don'y really care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think of it like a triangle [image]

now just use simple geometry to find the length of the hypotenous

```
a**2+b**2 = c**2
latlon_dist**2+height_dist**2 = distance**2
distance = sqrt(latlon_dist**2+height_dist**2)
```

Comment: I am aware of how to find the distance in x/y/z the problem is that, the earth is a spheroid, though that might work for the very short distances I am using

Comment: see this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108965/taking-altitude-into-account-when-calculating-geodesic-distance

Comment: Ran some tests with around 200m it seems to agree within 3 digits with this: http://cosinekitty.com/compass.html  thanks! can't believe I didn't think of that before.