# Distance between 2 GPS coordinates with Bearing, Altitude, speed

Tags: geolocation, gps, geospatial

Basically I am getting answers with only 2 GPS coordinates sometimes with bearing or altitude. But how do I combine all three together to get the distance between two points?

**Edit:**
All my points are pretty close, i.e. distance lie between few meters to 10 km max. Can I optimize by removing some of the above parameters for such close points?

Some similar questions, although not exact:-

[Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates): There is an answer taking bearing in consideration, way below.

[Taking altitude into account when calculating geodesic distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108965/taking-altitude-into-account-when-calculating-geodesic-distance): Altitude in the calculation